# Issue with deploying PHP Application to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a customized PHP application I am trying to deploy using Elastic Beanstalk. To deploy using ELB, I have zipped up the code and uploaded. I'm having trouble getting it to deploy correctly. Is there a correct way to zip and deploy?

Following errors showing up:

[Instance: i-1z123x1111a1z9999] Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].

Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].

Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-1z123x1111a1z9999'. Aborting the operation.

Failed to deploy application.

During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.

Please guide in any way possible.

Thanks

Comment: Can you inspect the logs and identify which command failed?

Comment: following errors in can-init.log file: [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2020-07-06 18:09:11,201 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Yum does not have mod24_ssl available for installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the other conversation, the error

```
Yum does not have mod24_ssl available for installation
```

is due to fact that `PHP 7.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3` is used. `mod24_ssl` is only avaiablie on **Amazon Linux 1**, not **Amazon Linux 2**.

On **Amazon Linux 2**, the package is called `mod_ssl`. Thus to install it the following command can be used

```
sudo yum install -y mod_ssl
```

Comment: I was able to deploy using Amazon Linux 1 successfully.

Comment: @NetSystemAdmin Glad to hear it worked out :-) Thanks. And the second issue also got solved?

Comment: Is there any way to get EB to use mod_ssl, or is reverting to Linux 1 the only solution? I'm trying to upgrade PHP from 7.2 to 8.0 and Linux 2 is the only available option

Comment: @ironic_ollins I'm not sure. You could make new question for this.